# Salesforce Audience Studio integration with Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, audiencestudio

I am trying to integrate Saelsforce Audience Studio (DMP) with Marketing cloud ? To include User pixels in the emails sent by marketing cloud, what are the steps to be followed ?

Comment: https://konsole.zendesk.com/hc/en-us is the resource for AudienceStudio

Comment: There is also a code snippet you can add called "Salesforce Audience Studio Pixel" in the drop down box

Comment: Hi @EazyE , that drop down itself I am not currently getting. How to make setting in Marketing cloud that I can get it in the Code Snippet drop down ?

Comment: Does that account have audience studio provisioned ?

Comment: Nope. how to provision it, can I do it by myself or only Salesforce support can do it ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to purchase it. I would reach out to your account team

Comment: We have bought Audience Studio, I have access to it. It is just not connected to Marketing cloud.

Comment: So, here are the steps 

Log into Email Studio > Navigate to "Admin" >> "Salesforce Audience Studio Integration" and the pixel setup screen should appear.

These values need to be acquired by raising a case to Salesforce Audience Studio.

Once this setup is complete, we will be able to add Audience Studio Pixels in the emails in Marketing cloud.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more focused. And also commented the solution the way it worked for me. 
Could this question be re-opened for others to view my solution comment. Thanks.